# getting "URL key for specified store already exists." error when trying to apply data patch to update a cms page

Tags: cms-pages, data-patch

I am trying to update a cms page through a data patch but, the patch is not applying. I get this error below

```
Unable to apply data patch Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data\CreateRegistryPage for module vendor_module. Original exception message: URL key for specified store already exists.
```

I have the below code for my data patch

```
class CreateRegistryPage implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PatchContextInterface
     */
    private $patchContext;
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    private $pageFactory;

    /**
     * CreateRegistryPage constructor.
     * @param PatchContextInterface $patchContext
     * @param PageFactory $pageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        PatchContextInterface $patchContext,
        PageFactory $pageFactory
    ) {
        $this->patchContext = $patchContext;
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [
            AddHeroInformationToHomePage::class
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function apply(): void
    {
        $template = $this->patchContext->template()
                ->get(<vendor_module>, 'registry-page');
        $this->patchContext->media()->copyModuleMedia([
                'Magebit_StarRegistration::banner-image.jpg' => 'occasions/banner-image.jpg'
        ]);

        $pageData = [
                'title' => 'International Star Registry',
                'content_heading' => 'International star registry',
                'page_layout' => 'registry',
                'identifier' => 'international-star-registry',
                'content' => $template,
                'is_active' => 1,
                'stores' => [0],
                'constellation_name' => 'What are you waiting for? {{orange}}Name a star now!{{/orange}}',
                'constellation_summary' => "<p>This is a standard star, which can be observed throughout the year in the sky from worldwide without any specific accessories. It’s a great value for the money and truly amazing gift.</p>",
                'constellation_image' => 'image_certificate.png',
                'occasions_image' => 'banner-image.jpg'
        ];

        $this->pageFactory->create()->setData($pageData)->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **update** update an existing item, you should use `load` method to load the item and then set data and save the item.
Replace your `apply` method with the following:

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function apply(): void
{
    $internationalStarRegistryPage = $this->pageFactory->load('international-star-registry', 'identifier');

    if ($internationalStarRegistryPage->getId()) {
        $template = $this->patchContext->template()->get(<vendor_module>, 'registry-page');
        $this->patchContext->media()->copyModuleMedia([
            'Magebit_StarRegistration::banner-image.jpg' => 'occasions/banner-image.jpg'
        ]);
    
        $pageData = [
            'title' => 'International Star Registry',
            'content_heading' => 'International star registry',
            'page_layout' => 'registry',
            'identifier' => 'international-star-registry',
            'content' => $template,
            'is_active' => 1,
            'stores' => [0],
            'constellation_name' => 'What are you waiting for? {{orange}}Name a star now!{{/orange}}',
            'constellation_summary' => "<p>This is a standard star, which can be observed throughout the year in the sky from worldwide without any specific accessories. It’s a great value for the money and truly amazing gift.</p>",
            'constellation_image' => 'image_certificate.png',
            'occasions_image' => 'banner-image.jpg'
        ];
    
        $internationalStarRegistryPage->setData($pageData);
        $internationalStarRegistryPage->save();
    }
}
```